# How can I express data dependencies with Backbone MVC?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller

I have a singleton collection that will very rarely change, but is not static data. Let's say that it's a list of possible shapes that objects can have:

```
var Shape = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Shapes = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: "/mydata"
});
Shapes.fetch()
```

I have a model and associated collection which is for the models that my views will interact with. We'll call them structures:

```
var Structure = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.vecs = some_utility_function(options.shape);
  }
});

var Structures = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Structure,
  create: function(options) {
    var shape = options.shape || Shapes.get("weird_square");
    return new Structure(Shapes.get("weird_square"));
  }
});
```

The problem is in the collection's `create` function: the call to `Shapes.get()` won't work until the Shapes collection has fired `sync` at least once.

So there's already a complexity issue: now my views need to know that they need to wait for a `sync` event from the `Shapes` collection before they can call `create()` on the Structures collection to get a new model instances.

Even worse: my views might never even **see** the sync, because it'll get a response pretty quickly and a lot of other stuff needs  to happen before these views are created.

The only solutions I can think of are:

- a monstrous higher-level view or model that knows everything that needs to be ready before my views and models can talk to each other, and somehow resolves those dependencies before doing anything. That's achievable, but it's difficult to maintain and any structure I give it will seem arbitrary
- changing the code in the collection's `create` so that it's really just giving out a stub instance of the model, and only once the Shapes collection is ready does it fill fire a callback to fill that object in and call `sync` on the model instance. This sucks a bit, because now `sync` on the model could mean "the object has actually been created for real now" as well as its usual meaning of being synced with the server.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) and, since jQuery is a dependency, [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), to synchronize your objects. For example, you could modify your `Structures` class to include an `extrude` method<sup>1</sup>  that returns a promise :

```
var Structures = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Structure,
    extrude: function(options) {
        options = options || {};
        var dfd = $.Deferred();

        if (options.shape) {
            // resolved immediately
            dfd.resolve(new Structure(options.shape));
        } else {
            // resolved when Shapes.fetch completes
            Shapes.fetch().then(function() {
                dfd.resolve(new Structure(Shapes.get("weird_square")));
            });
        }
        return dfd.promise();
    }
});
```

In your views, you would use this promise to "wait" for the model. The behavior is the same, whatever `Structures.extrude` has to do to build your `Structure` model

```
var s = new Structures();

// without shapes.get
s.extrude({shape: {}}).then(function(m) {
    console.log(m);
});

// with shapes.get
s.extrude().then(function(m) {
    console.log(m);
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/xMSJ6/ .

If you want a single `fetch` to occur on the lifetime of your `Shapes` object, you can override its `fetch` method to return the same xhr object every time :

```
Shapes.fetch = function() {
    if (!this.__xhr) {
        this.__xhr = Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this);
    }
    return this.__xhr;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/xMSJ6/1/

<sup>1</sup> `create` is used by `Backbone.Collection`, overriding it may or may not be what you want

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. A convention of something like `extrude` returning a promise from all my models or collections is easy to keep consistent everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few of other approaches you can add to your list of possibilities. Not all of these are a good idea.

1. If your list of `Shape`s rarely changes, it seems like it's a good candidate for [bootstrapping via JSON](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap). Rather than have your Backbone app run `collection.fetch` or `collection.sync` on startup, you can instantiate your `Shapes` immediately from the JSON included in your HTML. This also saves you a round trip to the server; if possible, I think this is the best option.
2. Load the 'weird_square' `Shape` from JSON. If you can't load the entire set of `Shapes` via JSON, maybe you can load your default `Shape` when your page loads, and `sync` the others in later.
3. Instantiate your `Structures` from within a success callback on the `Shapes.fetch`. But this seems like it's pushing the problem down lower; now your app has to check whether `Structures` is defined yet before attempting to use it. But if this is your only dependency, a two-step initialiser might be OK. Create the `Shapes`, `fetch()` it from the server, and do the rest of your setup in a [success callback](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync).
4. Use [events and an event bus](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) to sync your app. Your `Shapes` collection could fire a `shapes:loaded` message, which dependent objects can listen for and set themselves up at that point. [`listenToOnce`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenToOnce) may be useful here.
5. Lazy-load your `Shape` in your `Structure`. Rather than storing a `Shape` object itself, store the *name* of the shape instead. It might be hard to control interactions with your `Structure`, though (I can't think of a nice way to block calls to `myStructure.getShape()` until the `Shapes` are loaded). Depending on your app, you may be able to disable certain parts of your interface until the data has loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. #1 seems best as you say, but unfortunately it's not possible in my environment.